# upload image to Imgur throw Image format not supported, or image is corrupt

Tags: javascript, php, image, base64, imgur

I'm trying to upload an `image` to `Imgur` using `PHP` , by sending the `Image Base64String` as an input :

```
  function el(id) {
                        return document.getElementById(id);
                    } 

                    function readImage() {
                        if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
                            var FR = new FileReader();
                            FR.onload = function (e) {
                                el("img").src = e.target.result;
                                el("base").innerHTML = e.target.result.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
                            };
                            FR.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
                        }
                    }

                    el("file").addEventListener("change", readImage, false);
                });
```

the result is :

```
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
```

when I editing the `img` element with the result , it works and I see the `Image` , but when I send it to `Imgur` it says : `Image format not supported, or image is corrupt`, what I'm missing here?